# jqGrid wrap text inline edit

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Is it possible to wrap text of a cell while inline editing the cell? I tried several things but no effect:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
       white-space: normal !important;
   }

   .ui-jqgrid td textarea {
        white-space: normal !important;
   }
</style>
```

The first setting works in the non-edit mode, the second setting has no effect (while editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set

```
edittype: 'textarea'
```

(in stead of text), no CSS needed. You can even specify rows and columns:

```
editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}
```